# Form.ShowDialog in another thread

Tags: .net, winforms

In main thread I created a worker thread that creates a new form and calls `form.showDialog`. After calling `form.Close` the application dies.

Why is this happening?

```
//called from someone worker thread. not from main thread
    void s_notificationAgent_AgentError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectingForm form = new ConnectionForm();
            form.ShowDialog();//if i close form clicking on button. app dies(

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }                       
    }
```

UPD: because I do not have the right to respond to this question
     i answered question in 'edit':)
after googling i found that..

the cause is that you're accessing the Application object on a thread other than the thread it was created on. The solution is to invoke a method onto the thread that created the Application object (or the owner).

it helped me:)

```
    //called from someone worker thread. not from main thread
    void s_notificationAgent_AgentError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
            //through the synchContext calling methods from GUI thread
         winContext.Send(_=> {form = new Form1();},null);   
         winContext.Send(_=> form.ShowDialog(),null);                                              
    }
```

Comment: What you you have wanted to happen instead? Can you show some code exhibiting the unwanted behavior?

Comment: I expect that dialog forms simply closes without killing my app.

Comment: I think it's necessary to show some code in order to get an answer to this question. Please show how your application is run (the `Main` method) and how you create and display the form.

Comment: i update post. important that method called from some worker thread.

Comment: What is your main thread doing?

Comment: ConnectingForm is just dummy form at this moment with one button "Сlose" and code ..this.Close();(

Comment: Yes, but the question is *what is the main thread doing*? What code is that thread executing while the worker thread displays the dialog? What does your `Main` method look like? The problem is not likely in the dialog or worker thread, but rather in the main thread.

Comment: nothing..simple admin form..when connection with server broken the  s_notificationAgent_AgentError method handle with situation

Comment: No thread ever does nothing. It either executes code, or is waiting to execute code at a specific location. Unless you post the actual code, there is no help to get here. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for help) problem solved ^^
solution i described in 'answer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All UI code runs on a single thread.  Once that thread has ended, the application has ended, the message pump is torn down, etc.

In your worker thread, you need to create a new application and run your from on it, just like your program does when it starts up (usually this code is generated for you).  Look in your program.cs to see this generated code, and copy and paste it to your worker thread.

Something like this:
`System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(new MyDialogInTheWorkerThread());`

Comment: So replacing `form.ShowDialog();` with `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(form);` still resulted in the same behavior?

Comment: yes. i think founded problem.
solution described in question:)
maybe not best solution...in any case, now everything works

Thank you for taking part in solving the problem:)